# Answer "Enter Your Coice: [1-3]" via Shell Script

Tags: linux, ubuntu, shell-script

I have a problem in my shell script. I try to control an installation.
During the installation there are a few questions which have to be answered.
Like: "Enter your Choice [1-3]: "

I want do something like this:

```
--> It's my first script <--
#!/bin/bash


echo "--> Install packages <--"
sudo apt-get install git

cd $HOME/

#mkdir mspgcc_download
#cd mspgcc_download

echo "--> Download mspgcc <--" 

git clone git://mspgcc4.git.sourceforge.net/gitroot/mspgcc4/mspgcc4
cd mspgcc4

echo "--> Build mspgcc <--" 

echo "y" | echo "n" | echo "" | echo "n" | echo "2" | echo "1" | echo "1" | echo "1" | ./buildgcc.sh
```

Comment: there's an edit function for your question, please learn to use it instead of adding 'answers' to add more information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can often do that with a [here doc](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html#SEC45):

```
cat <<EOF | ./buildgcc.sh
y
n

n
2
1
1
1
EOF
```

or

```
./buildgcc.sh <<EOF
y
n

n
2
1
1
1
EOF
```

Answer (score 3):

`echo` will print to the standard output, that is, what you see in the terminal. You have to pipe the data into the standard input of your application, usually with `|`.

```
echo 1 | your-prog-here
```

Perhaps you should be using [expect](http://linux.die.net/man/1/expect), but it is new programming language you will have to learn.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ read -p 'Gimme a B: ' b
bee
$ echo $b
bee
```

Answer (score 1):

If i've well understood your query, I often use this kind of code :

```
_answer=''
while [ -z ${_answer} ]
do
    # I check if Bash or Ksh is used
    if [ "x${BASH_VERSION}" != "x" -a "x${KSH_VERSION}" = "x" ]; then
        # Bash
        read -n 1 -p "Your choice [1-3] : " _answer
    else
        # KSH
        read  _answer?"Your choice [1-3] : "
    fi
    clear
    case "${_answer}" in
        1) function1 ;;
        2) function2 ;;
        3) function3 ;;
        *) _answer='' ;;
    esac
done
```

The difference in the read syntax, let's you only type the character on Bash, but you must type an enter at the end with KSH. For bash, it's the `-n 1` that say to read to only wait for 1 character.

Don't forget to declare your function before.